# Advice about function calling conventions when using sockets

Tags: sockets, winsock, calling-convention, winsock2

I plan to use sockets to make function calls between a client 32 bit application and a 64 bit application.

What would be the best scheme to call functions, pass variables and return parameters via the socket interface. I have control over both the client and the server code so I can implement anything.

I was thinking, to have the socket packet being made up of:
- 1 word: length (# of characters) of the function name
- string: the actual function name
- 1 word: length (in bytes) of the function parameters
- function parameters

Please let me know, what would be the most robust and extensible approaches. Maybe I can reuse principles used by calling conventions by compilers, web services or virtual machines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason you are limited to sockets, why not WCF?

Comment: You seem to be reinventing COM and (shudder) CORBA.

Comment: @David, i am not limited to sockets.

Comment: thanks guys, I am reading up on what you mentioned. I would need to transfer a content of a file a few mb and return an indexed faceset mesh. C++ is the language used on windows platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use Protocol Buffers for the serialization:

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/index.html

Tutorial:

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html

When you send the object to the other side, start with a length prefix (32bit int) which defines how many bytes you should read to get a complete protobuf message.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i had already considered this to serialize the data, I still have the question about function calling convention

Comment: That's specified in the protbuf defintion.

Comment: Here is a complete RPC library using protobuf: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-remote/ It should take care of everything for you.